# Why can't I use subscripting on a CKRecord object in swift?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

This has bothered me for a little while. Is there a reason why I need to do this to set an object on a CKRecord.

```
task.record?.setObject(task.reference, forKey:ReferenceField)
```

instead of this

```
task.record?[ReferenceField] = task.reference
```

From what I read in the docs CKRecord should be subscript friendly

Comment: It even says in the header file:
    In addition to objectForKey: and setObject:forKey:,
    dictionary-style subscripting (record[key] and record[key] = value)  
    can be used to get and set values.

Answer (score 4):

That subscripting is only available from Objective-C, since it's implemented using `objectForKeyedSubscript:` and `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:`. Happily, it's easy to extend `CKRecord` to allow Swift subscripting:

```
extension CKRecord {
    subscript(key: String) -> AnyObject! {
        get {
            return self.objectForKey(key)
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self.setObject(newValue as CKRecordValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

NSHipster has [a post on Objective-C subscripting](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/) if you want to know more. I'm surprised Swift doesn't bridge that automatically.

Comment: This causes a stack overflow for me, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27159950/27779

Comment: @Gregory: This is very true. I guess that's why it's not subscripted by default. Maybe Apple will come later with a native CKrecord subscript.