# Stack overflow when defining subscript on CKRecord in Swift

Tags: swift, cloudkit, subscript-operator, ckrecord

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27108714/27779) asks whether one can use subscripting with `CKRecord` in Swift. While I already knew how to do what the questioner wanted, every permutation of it gives me a stack overflow:

```
subscript(key: String) -> CKRecordValue? {
    get {
        return objectForKey(key) as CKRecordValue?
    }
    set {
        setObject(newValue, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

The stack overflow occurs in the getter. (I've never tried the setter, so it may occur there, too.) I've tried implementing with `objectForKey:`, `objectForKeyedSubscript:`, and `valueForKey:`. All produce the same result: a stack overflow.

This is very strange, since `CKRecord` is certainly written in Objective-C. Why would it recursively call Swift's `subscript` method? It makes no sense. Nate Cook, in his answer to the questioner, wonders why Swift doesn't bridge `objectForKeyedSubscript:` automatically. Well, maybe the code to do that is not fully baked, but is causing this problem. I will have to try it with another class that has `objectForKeyedSubscript:`.

## UPDATE

It appears that `objectForKeyedSubscript:` is ordinarily bridged. I created a class in Objective-C with the appropriate methods, added it to the bridging header, and the indexers were there and compiled without issue. Even better, it worked without a stack overflow.

This means that something very unusual is going on with `CKRecord`.

## A THEORY

If you create a class in Swift that descends from `NSObject` and implements the `subscript` method on it with a `String` as the key, this becomes `objectForKeyedSubscript:`. (For "pure Swift" classes, I suspect this is not the case.) You can verify this by importing your Swift class into Objective-C and verifying that `objectForKeyedSubscript:` is there.

Since `CKRecord` descends from `NSObject`, implementing `subscript` overrides the default implementation. Further, it seems that `objectForKey:` and `valueForKey:` all ultimately called `objectForKeyedSubscript:`, which results in (read: "is the same as") a call to `subscript`, which causes the stack overflow.

That may explain why the stack overflow occurs. It still does not explain why `objectForKeyedSubscript:` was not automatically bridged, but perhaps it's because the definition of `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` has a slightly different type signature from the canonical one: `- (void)setObject:(id <CKRecordValue>)object forKeyedSubscript:(NSString *)key;`. This makes no difference to Objective-C, but might trip up the "bridging code". Swift is pretty new, after all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CKRecord but it sounds to me like a bug report to Apple wouldn't be a wrong move here.

Comment: Agreed. Now that I think I've figured it out, that's exactly what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing and debugging (via a subclass), I discovered that, for `CKRecord`, `objectForKey:` does indeed call `objectForKeyedSubscript:`. Also, implementing `subscript` in a Swift class that is marked `@objc` implicitly (by descending from `NSObject`) or explicitly means that `subscript` is implemented as `objectForKeyedSubscript:`.

This means that implementing `subscript` on `CKRecord` in an extension hides the default implementation, which causes the stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a simple extension to CKRecord to make it easier to subscript with.

```
extension CKRecord {
    struct Sub {
        let record: CKRecord

        subscript(key: String) -> CKRecordValue? {
            get {
                return record.objectForKey(key) as? CKRecordValue
            }
            set {
                record.setObject(newValue, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }

    var sub: Sub {
        return Sub(record: self)
    }

    var : Sub {
        return sub
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var sub = record.sub
sub["name"] = name

/* Or */

// One does not simply subscript CKRecord
record.["name"] = name
```

---

(I’m kidding about the  by the way)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully subscript by piggy-backing off of some code written by an Apple engineer on dev forums.

```
import CloudKit

protocol MyCKRecordValueType {
    var asObject: CKRecordValue { get }
}

extension CKRecord {
    func set<ValueType>(value: ValueType, forKey key: String) where ValueType : MyCKRecordValueType {
        let object = value.asObject
        self.setObject(object, forKey: key)
    }
    subscript(key : String) -> MyCKRecordValueType? {
        set {
            self.setObject(newValue?.asObject, forKey: key)
        }
        get {
            return object(forKey: key) as? MyCKRecordValueType
        }
    }
}

extension String : MyCKRecordValueType {
    var asObject: CKRecordValue { return self as NSString }
}
extension Bool : MyCKRecordValueType {
    var asObject: CKRecordValue { return self as NSNumber }
}
extension Int : MyCKRecordValueType {
    var asObject: CKRecordValue { return self as NSNumber }
}
extension Data : MyCKRecordValueType {
    var asObject: CKRecordValue { return self as NSData }
}
```

you can then call the subscript as you would expect:

```
let firstRecordID = CKRecordID(recordName: "0")

        let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Foo", recordID: firstRecordID)

        record["title"] = "Hello World"

        record["year_established"] = 2000
```