# Does subscript operator work for CKRecord?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord

I want to use subscript operator like docs show: `myRecord[@"firstName"] = @"Jacob";`

but can't get it to work in Swift.

Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Please do your research, looks like you are posting a lot of CloudKit questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108714/why-cant-i-use-subscripting-on-a-ckrecord-object-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this post you can see an explanation why subscripting CKRecord does not work and why you also can not add your own.

[Stack overflow when defining subscript on CKRecord in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159950/stack-overflow-when-defining-subscript-on-ckrecord-in-swift)

There is however a sample of a workaround that comes close.